# Isolated singularity of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ along points in general position

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose we are ginen $m$ points in $\mathbb{P}^3$ in general position. Can we give an effective bound on $m$ such that there is no degree $d$ irreducible hypersurface having isolated singularity along the given $m$ points ?

Comment: If the $m$ points are general points, then each of the $m$ singularity conditions are linearly independent.  Also, each singularity condition defines a subvariety of codimension $4$ (until the linear system has dimension strictly less than $4$).  Thus, when $4m \geq \binom{d+3}{3}$, there is no nonzero homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ that has singularities at those points.

Comment: @JasonStarr: "If the m points are general points, then each of the m singularity conditions are linearly independent" Why? I think that this is already an open problem for nodal curves. Anyway, the claim is false for non-irreducible hypersurfaces: if you take five points in general position on the plane, the expected dimension of the linear system plane quartics with double points at them is -1, so you do not expect any of them, but of course there is the (unique) double conic.

Comment: This is a survey for the corresponding problem for curves: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3db0/6dd64b62f15f04c9caa13dba2db7ca4d9fdd.pdf

Comment: Francesco Polizzi is correct.  The condition to vanish to order $1$ at $m$ general points does give linearly independent conditions.  The condition to vanish to higher order often does not give linearly independent conditions.  That was careless of me.  I have one paper about "asymptotic Harbourne-Hirschowitz-(Gimigliano-Segre)" results, so particularly embarassing.

Comment: @JasonStarr: well, sometimes I have difficulties in following the arguments in my own oldest papers :-)

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi:  Is the claim  true for irreducible hypersurfaces ? i.e., if $4m \ge h^0(\mathcal{O}(d))$, then can we say there does not exist any irreducible degree $d$ hypersurface with singularity at given $m$ points ?

Comment: @user130022: I think this is an open problem (for plane curves, look at Harbourne-Hirschowitz conjecture).

Comment: Is it known for degree $5$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ ?

Comment: there is a result by A. Beauville, that a degree $5$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ can have at most $31$ isolated singularity.  Let $23 \le m \le 31$. Is it possible to find an irreducible degree $5$ hypersurface with $m$ singularity among which there are $15$ points are general?